# GT5 Racing Daytona in Nascar

Tags: gran-turismo-5

I'm currently racing the A-Spec Extreme series, and despite having won the Nascar Series with a gold, the last race, the best I can do is last. Last by about 15 seconds!

I managed to start lapping about 43s a lap and then it seems to drop off to about 47-48s a lap.

I noticed that I'm losing speed in the corners whereas the computer drivers, watching the replay at least can corner at 198-202mph, whereas I'm running about 185mph, which is losing my seconds lap on lap.

Are there any tips? Setup tricks? Or advice for racing this race? I've tried Soft compound racing tyres, tweaking up and down downforce, and tinkering with suspension, but I can't seem to corner fast enough to stick with the pack.

I do understand that Nascar is aggressive and you do need to block the line and train to draft and such, but you need to be in the pack to do that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick with NASCAR driving is to turn off the ABS. That was the only way I could complete the Jeff Gordon special events.

Comment: Cool! I'll give this is a try